# request.get(url) not working in python

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to access a url through the `request.get(url)` method. It is showing the error:

```
raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jawbone.com', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/oauth2/token?&client_id=ln1Fmh0-_fM&client_secret=6347a817372fe10c8168a6b2a08cdb6d2c0eb359&grant_type=authorization_code&code=aV1SI82xvTorFfSJUj4SV2na6cgo2_v-uVoO6syutrvyigmX5T19dxgi1Notq2BX3S9lsTYELynpGgsuWgbWr--GVkL4W468gA0vox9BEJVeQaE-y_Ag1qIwg5Jnf2wau806cG3fyeIbb4kkn8mrrqgZaLdBfBAfXaCH7rMkJ9avUszB10Lbxx5Ft_tbuFx2pe4N3piQM1xAKMXNVOTe6nt573H32ynarIFYoy5Otuw
(Caused by <class 'TimeoutError'>: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

When I try to access the same url using webrowser (url), it is working fine, but I am not able to get the response object.

code is as follows

```
def getAccessToken(self, code):
     u = 'jawbone.com/auth/oauth2/token?';
     u += '&client_id=' + self.client_id 
     u += '&client_secret=' + self.client_secret 
     u += '&grant_type=authorization_code' 
     u += '&code=' + code 
     print(u) 
     res = requests.get(u) 
     if res.status_code == 200: 
         print('success') 
        return json.loads(res) 
     else:
        return res
```

Comment: did you check it against a non secured url? something like http://www.cnn.com ?

Comment: Also, please can you share the Python code you're using to make the `requests.get()` request?

Comment: Please add this to your question and use the code formatting.

Comment: I think there is some proxy authentication required for the url.How can i do that?

Comment: Hope you have obfuscated your client_id & client_secret before posting your error message here, else change delete the existing & regenerate them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your request in the browser and what it displays is:

> {
>   error_description: "Authentication code has expired: aV1SI82xvTorFfSJUj4SV2na6cgo2_v-uVoO6syutrvyigmX5T19dxgi1Notq2BX3S9lsTYELynpGgsuWgbWr--GVkL4W468gA0vox9BEJVeQaE-y_Ag1qIwg5Jnf2wau806cG3fyeIbb4kkn8mrrqgZaLdBfBAfXaCH7rMkJ9avUszB10Lbxx5Ft_tbuFx2pe4N3piQM1xAKMXNVOTe6nt573H32ynarIFYoy5Otuw",
>   error: "invalid_request"
>   }

And then I use `requests.get()` to emit a request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#coding: utf-8

import requests

url = 'https://jawbone.com/auth/oauth2/token?/auth/oauth2/token?&client_id=ln1Fmh0-_fM&client_secret=6347a817372fe10c8168a6b2a08cdb6d2c0eb359&grant_type=authorization_code&code=aV1SI82xvTorFfSJUj4SV2na6cgo2_v-uVoO6syutrvyigmX5T19dxgi1Notq2BX3S9lsTYELynpGgsuWgbWr--GVkL4W468gA0vox9BEJVeQaE-y_Ag1qIwg5Jnf2wau806cG3fyeIbb4kkn8mrrqgZaLdBfBAfXaCH7rMkJ9avUszB10Lbxx5Ft_tbuFx2pe4N3piQM1xAKMXNVOTe6nt573H32ynarIFYoy5Otuw'

res = requests.get(url)
print res.content
```

The content it prints is the same the that the browser displays. There's nothing wrong to happen.

Comment: i think there is some proxy authentication that is required in my system.How can i specify that.

Comment: @Anukuttan, refer to this doc [requests-proxies](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies)

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the rate limit (you are sending too many requests to the server).
identify the maximum rate you are assigned and sleep (`time.sleep(x)`) for a few seconds before hititng the limit